# Hub id from hubs/:hub_id/projects not returning or matching hub id

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

For our app (ACC integration to our platform), the first step we present to users after they get a token is a list of accounts/hubs and a list of projects.

The hubs are returned from: developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs ([docs](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/))

The projects are returned from: developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/:hub_id/projects ([docs](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/)) for each hub id we get from /hubs.

According to the docs and consistent with our testing, the projects in the response include data.relationships.hub.id.

We're then doing a basic filter to show projects by account/hub user selection to make it easier for users to find the project they want to use.

This all works as expected for us with the account we have access to and the projects under it. The projects return with the hub id that matches the hub id we used to get the project. We've confirmed the filtering/project selection works in our testing with any response data we have access to from the endpoints mentioned above.

However, the internal Autodesk test team is having problems with the project filtering when selecting an account. Could the data.relationships.hub.id not be returning with the hub id's used to get them?

Are there any scenarios or nuances we might not be aware of that could cause this discrepancy or anything unexpected like this, where a project may not show as being related to one of their accounts (i.e. data.relationships.hub.id from the projects endpointdoes not match data.id from the hubs endpoint)?

Comment: When you say accounts could the reason be it's missing the prefix of "b." when this is actually a Hub? I'm not aware of any issue or scenarios that would make this a difference to what you are describing. Does the Test Team have their clientID registered also to make sure they have access?

Comment: @JaimeRosales thanks for your response. That doesn't seem to be it (I'm familiar with what you're describing), unless you're saying that in some cases the b prefix is used and others it isn't for the same entity type (e.g. like if in some cases BIM360 and ACC projects used different prefixes or are returned with different formats of the hubId property).